# Can electromagnetic waves be polarized without any being absorbed or blocked? (I.e., no energy is lost?)

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, polarization

I guess what I am asking is this:

When a light source is suddenly polarized in a certain direction, is it because all of the constituent waves not already polarized that way are blocked, reflected or absorbed?

Or, can all of the wave(s) and their energy be polarized a certain way by external electric and/or magnetic fields?  And then continue on their merry way?

Comment: i think:  There must an be an increase of EM momentum for this to happen which constitutes a loss of mechanical momentum, But for there to be a loss of mechanical momentum, There must be negative work done on charges, Which increases the EM energy hence invalidating our assumption that the energy is not lost/or gained in the EM field. I am however assuming that we are not transfering momentum to other parts of the EM field ( not associated with the wave in question)  and hence my line of reasoning may not be correct. if you allow for the wave to increase in energy, then this may be possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, polarizers (that turn unpolarized light into polarized light) are always blocking for the "unwanted" polarization. So they are lossy. That is they block one orientation of circular polarized light (left or right handed) or the horizontal or vertical polarization for the linear polarizer.

There are components that can do a polarization rotation or alteration, but they will not turn unpolarized light into polarized one.
These materials are birefringent, i.e. they have different refractive index for the polarization states (circular or linear).
This includes materials that turn birefringent when applying a magnetic or electric field. They will do a (adjustable) polarization rotation, i.e. an adjustment.

So materials with or without electric or magnitic field will not make polarized light out of unpolarized one in a lossless fashion. (At least I do not see how this could happen)

The circular polarization is connected with the photon spin. It can be left or right handed. Polarized light would then only consitute of photons of the same spin orientation.

In other words, to make circular polarized light out of unpolarized light one has to "flip" the photons of one spin orientation to the other one. This can only be done through interaction with matter.
I do not know any way to do this directly (i.e. without absorption and re-emission). Note that angular momentum has to be conserved, so to flip photons one needs to create opposite angular momentum elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that light is made of individual photons. I the light is unpolarized then all the photons have random polarizations. When they interact with a polarizer then on average 50% will transit and 50% will be absorbed. When light is vertically polarized, then the **individual** (vertically polarized photons) will pass through a vertical polarizer but they will be absorbed by a horizontal polarizer.
When vertically polarized photons interact with a polarizer set at some angle in between then they will transit at COS2THETA

Answer (score 0):

In practice we cannot, filters and reflection polarizers either absorb some part of beam energy or split the unpolarized beam into two or more polarized beams. The latter case can be lossless as a whole, but each of the two beams of different polarization and direction has only a part of energy of the original beam.

Due to random fluctuations in an unpolarized beam, it seems unlikely a passive system could organize the unpolarized wave into linearly polarized wave without energy losses.

But theoretically, it should be possible to organize a low frequency unpolarized beam into polarized one, using active methods (using additional source of energy), at least partially (this is just a scientific speculation):

1. measure electric field vector components $E_x,E_y$ of the unpolarized wave in medium as functions of time at one point of the beam;
2. send this information downstream to a powerful adaptive optical system;
3. use that information to manipulate state of various lossless optical elements in the system (using total reflection and angle-dependent and polarization-dependent phase shifts) to rotate the polarization by the right amount in order to produce a linearly polarized wave.

But this would require additional energy in the measuring and adaptive modifying system, which would get dissipated. So it would not really be a lossless process on the whole, just in the sense that the beam intensity would be preserved.

Comment: how would you classify Faraday effect/rotation in this context? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect

Comment: @hyportnex The Faraday Effect is just (circular) birefringence induced by a magnetic field. Refractive index is different for two (circular) polarization axes. This effect will not turn one polarization into another (at least I do not see how this could be done).

Comment: @hyportnex Fixed magnetic field causing the Faraday effect could be a passive element, if it used permanent magnet instead of electromagnet. Using such element to organize the beam would require changing the magnetic field to change to angle of rotation of polarization based on polarization fluctuations in the beam, so then it wouldn't be passive.

Comment: @JánLalinský my own experience with birefrigerent ferrites in the microwave range were always using permanent magnets (circulators, isolators). My question was not a trick one, I really was not sure what the question actually was really about.

Comment: @AndreasH Since the the sum of L & R is a linear polarization, if the ferrite is long enough it rotates a vertical into a horizontal, in fact it can be any direction, exactly because of the difference in phase velocities for the L and R circular polarizations.

Comment: @hyportnex Yes true, but how you want to convert a unpolarized beam into a polarized one? Even if you have a electric magnet and can adjust the amount of polarization riotation, your feedback loop probably needs to work with speeds up to optical frequencies and second it would not handle the spatial inhomogeneity of polarization. Also I am not sure if it is theoretically possible.

Comment: @AndreasH I misunderstood the question, *unpolarized* is not *unknown polarized*, my bad ...

Comment: @hyportnex Sure, no problem :-) But yes, "unknown polarization" would be a very different story...

Comment: Now we have a question.  What's makes radio waves different in this regard?  We have a simple quantum mechanical notion of unpolarized light: imagine an ensemble of identically prepared beams.  Measure the polarization of one, and the polarization of the other.  There is no correlation between the two.  But this is too simple.  If we take the two measurements in very close time order, a wavelength or two, there *will* be a correlation.  Polarization, like temporal coherence, has a coherence length.  For radio it's  always "long" on the time scale of the detector. ...

Comment: ... But for unpolarized light, it's very short, shorter than what we can measure: the "simple" notion of polarization works.  So the issue becomes an engineering question.  The properties of ultrafast lasers and frequency combs makes me wonder if we can today measure polarization coherence.  Or in the not-so-distant future.  The OP's question is more subtle than it first appears.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to polarise EM radiation without using a polarising filter. If you periodically accelerate electrons all in the same direction, you will get polarised radiation, which, however, is oscillating and changing direction. To work in the visible range, you cannot use a radio wave generator, but you can use a [free-electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser).

Comment: The statements here are not wrong, as such, but this answer fully misses the point of the question. OP is asking about how an *existing* light source can be polarised, not whether one can make other light sources that are polarised.